# Using reagent/reactify-component to create React class for use in JSX

Tags: reactjs, clojure, clojurescript, reagent

I'm trying to adapt a Reagent (using re-frame) program that contains a component I want to be able to use from a plain React program. Essentially I to be able to take a Reagent (re-frame) component like this:

```
(defn my-component []
  (fn []
    (let [x (re-frame/subcribe [])]
      [:div (:something x)])))
```

Then, I want to have this render only when invoked from a `js` file, sort of like:

```
import myComponent from 'my-component'
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <myComponent
       x = "Hi"
       />
    );
  }
}
```

From all I can piece together it involves using `reagent/reactify-component` and/or `reagent/create-class`. But it's not very clear how these come together to make something a JS dev can use.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `reagent.core/as-element`, it receives a hiccup vector and returns a react element.